# bootstrap modal is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am very much poor in css.in my project i need a popup window.thats why i search on net and found/known about bootstrap modal. and trying to work with it.but i am facing problem. there are a lots of problem in stackoverflow already.but i thing my problems is different.thats why i am asking again?

problem=>
[image]

look above the box is appearing.and gone again without my instruction/without dowing anything.

my html=>

```
<div class="center"><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#squarespaceModal" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Click Me</button></div>

<!-- line modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="squarespaceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="lineModalLabel">My Modal</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <!-- content goes here -->
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
                    <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="group button">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" role="button">Close</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group btn-delete hidden" role="group">
                    <button type="button" id="delImage" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-red" data-dismiss="modal" role="button">Delete</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" id="saveImage" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-green" data-action="save" role="button">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my css=>

```
<style type="text/css">
.center {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.modal-header {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 0;
}

    .modal-footer .btn-group button {
        height: 40px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border: none;
        border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    .modal-footer .btn-group:last-child > button {
        border-right: 0;
    }
 </style>
```

and my head section=>

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link rel="icon" href="/Content/img/tsms/financial-literacy.gif" sizes="32x32">
<title>
    AdminTSMS
</title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<link href="/Content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-dialog.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/icheck/blue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Custom_Admin.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/skins/skin-blue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/Content/js/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/plugins/select2/select2.full.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/plugins/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/plugins/icheck/icheck.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/plugins/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/init.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Custom_Login.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MyCustomFile.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/run_prettify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

i am working on a project thats why there are lots of unnecessary staff.for better understanding i am giving you my full project head section.because i think the head section/links is one of the reason for the problem.css/bootstrap expert ? please help me.

Comment: One thing is that it Looks like you're loading bootstrap twice `<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>`  you only need one of those

Comment: you have included bootstrap at least 3 times that I can see, and the CSS at least twice. You've got two different datepicker plugins declared, and there are probably other duplications as well. This could be causing all sorts of bizarre conflicts. Sort out your includes and then see if you still have the same problem. Also check your browser console when this problem is occurring and see if any errors/warnings/logs appear which might give you a clue as to the reason for the strange behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, with properly included resources, your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vgLcndpf/42/

Comment: Also, this isnt causing problems but why have half your `js` in a `Scripts` folder and the other half in a `Content` folder? I'd clean up that whole project before going much further

Comment: @ADyson ... you are absolutely correct.and i want to know that..if there any problem if i add bootstrap 3 time...

Comment: @nayanchowdhury well I don't know exactly, but it seems likely to cause unexpected behaviour. DelightedDDD has already pointed out above that if you only include the files once, properly, then your existing code works fine, so it seems like that it's causing problems. Like I said, check your console, it might give you clues. Apart from that, the most definite problem is that you make your users download 3 times more data than they need to - slowing down the page load time, and chewing your bandwidth and your users.  And you have to maintain unnecessary code, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```css
.center {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.modal-header {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 0;
}

    .modal-footer .btn-group button {
        height: 40px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border: none;
        border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    .modal-footer .btn-group:last-child > button {
        border-right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="center"><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#squarespaceModal" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Click Me</button></div>

<!-- line modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="squarespaceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="lineModalLabel">My Modal</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <!-- content goes here -->
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
                    <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="group button">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" role="button">Close</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group btn-delete hidden" role="group">
                    <button type="button" id="delImage" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-red" data-dismiss="modal" role="button">Delete</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" id="saveImage" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-green" data-action="save" role="button">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```